# Hightlight jquery datepicker header selected day of the week

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to highlight the selected day (Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa) of the week in jquery datepicker header. Pay attention to the header in the next image (Tu is in bold text):

[image: highlight day in datepicker header]

The HTML of the days header section it' s like this:

[image]

What function or property of datepicker do I need to use to hightlight the selected day in the header ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for this.
You can use my sample as a workaround if you want :

```
  $('#js-date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var currentDate = new Date($('#js-date').val());
    $('.datepicker-days th.dow').removeClass('active')
    switch (currentDate.getDay()) {
      case 0:
        $('th.dow').eq(0).addClass('active');
        break;
      case 1:
        $('th.dow').eq(1).addClass('active');
        break;
      case 2:
        $('th.dow').eq(2).addClass('active');
        break;
      case 3:
        $('th.dow').eq(3).addClass('active');
        break;
      case 4:
        $('th.dow').eq(4).addClass('active');
        break;
      case 5:
        $('th.dow').eq(5).addClass('active');;
        break;
      case 6:
        $('th.dow').eq(6).addClass('active');
        break;
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sandwell/8qacnzd9/40/